# ReactNative: How to measure height of Text Input after programatic change

Tags: react-native

React Native has documentation for AutoExpandingTextInput: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

The Problem: When the content of the AutoExpandingTextInput is changed programmatically the height never changes.

For example:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
  this.setState({
    richText: this._addHighlights(props.richText)
  });
}

//

<AutoExpandingTextInput ref={component => this._text = component}>
  {this.state.richText}
</AutoExpandingTextInput>
```

Say, for example. the user hits a button that adds a link to the text that wraps to the next line; in this case, the AutoExpandingTextInput never expands, because the height only is measured & changed on the onChange event of the TextInput.

I need some work around to get the content height when no onChange is triggered --- or less ideally, a way to programmatically trigger an onChange to the TextInput.

Are there any solutions????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use the AutoExpandingTextInput plugin any more.  The functionality you need is supported (sort of) in react-native now and will resize with a programatic update.  Try something like this:

```
  _heightChange(event) {
    let height = event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height;
    if (height < _minHeight) {
      height = _minHeight;
    } else if (height > _maxHeight) {
      height = _maxHeight;
    }

    if (height !== this.state.height) {
      this.setState({height: height});
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        {...this.props}
        multiline={true}
        onContentSizeChange={this._heightChange.bind(this)}
      />
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked once I upgraded to react-native v0.31.0+ as the onContentSizeChange seems to only become available at that version.

Also, this seems to trigger a resize only when the text is first set. In order to trigger a resize programmatically on the TextInput I had to change the TextInput's key to recreate it. Of course, this would cause an onBlur, but in my use case the TextInput will not have focus when programmatically changing the content. 

Comment: What if textinput has default value and you want to calculate the height?